# Is vmware more secure than xp mode?

Tags: virtual-machine

Seem like the default sharing with host in xp mode ia very high risk while vmware kind of really separate vm and host. Any idea?

Comment: As far as I am aware, in VMware you have more control over the different settings of a Virtual Machine. But if I were you, I wouldn't measure the security of an application by its default settings: although, by default, Windows XP Mode may be more permissive as for sharing, if you are able to change this by editing the settings I will consider it secure as VMware.
However, if you are talking about encryption (In VMware you can encrypt a VM), I have no knowledge about the equivalent in Windows XP Mode, so I cannot compare the two.

Comment: yes, I am using xp mode with all sharing with host disable, then should be ok secured.

Comment: It depends on what security you need, actually. If you need that programs on the VM (virtual machine) won't be able to access your ost computer and vice versa, you're good. But if you need security which will require authorization in order to use the VM, I won't say it is secure.

Answer (score 0):

They are both equally secure in so far as you will probably never come across malware sophisticated enough to escape from its virtual prison.